# coldfusion application.cfm error log not logging all errors

Tags: logging, coldfusion, exception-logging

I have a Coldfusion application which uses a  tag in the application.cfm file.  This tag seems to be randomly logging errors.  There are errors in the Coldfusion error log.  I have been able to cause errors that get logged.  I have also heard user reports of errors which are not logged.

After doing some searching, I've found that application.cfc has trouble logging errors in some of the methods; however, I am not using application.cfc.

Wondering if anyone has run across the same behavior, and how to best handle.  I cannot debug application without the error information... any help would be appreciated

Comment: Any chance you can post your application.cfm code here?

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, I'd verify that when the user says "error" they don't mean "unexpected behavior".  My personal experinece is that anytime the system doesn't do what the end user thinks it should, that's an erorr, regardless of whether the site is behaving as intended.

Second, I'd make sure any try/catch blocks logged the error/warning/whatever, so you have a record of those problems.  This is probably not the issue, but it should be relatively easy to eliminate from the list of possible culprits.

Assuming that users are correctly reporting uncaught errors that are not getting logged, I'd ask the users to capture screenshots and let you know more about what they were trying to do, and the date/time of the erorr the next time they see one.  If nothing else, this may help you recreate it in a testing environment.

Comment: thanks 1)the template appears that would indicate that the cferror tag was executed.  2)thought all errors would get logged even if there is no try catch block (if cferror tag is in application.cfm)  is that inaccurate.  3) the screenshot is basically the generic error message, ive tried to get as much info from users as possible but in this case, what a user would know is probably not enough.  thanks for your help!

Comment: If nothing else, the screenshot should include the URL, which (though not as helpful as the full error) may help track down a problem.